# JQUERY UI Sort specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am working with a table where a single sortable column (DAYWEEK) needs to follow a specific sorting order. The column should be sorted not in an alphabetical order but following the day of the day of the week order.

```
$(tableId).puidatatable({
        paginator: {
            rows: params.rows,
        },
        ...
        columnResizeMode: 'expand',
        selectionMode: 'single',
        ...
        columns: gridColumns,
        datasource: function (callback, ui) ...
        ...
}

public static gridColumns = [
        { field: 'NAME', headerText: 'Name', headerClass: 'h_col', sortable: true, filter: true },
        ..
        { field: 'DAYWEEK', headerText: 'Day of the week', content: function (log: Log) { return log.DAYWEEK ? log.DAYWEEK : '' }, sortable: true }
    ];
```

Is there a way to specify for a specific column-field its sorting behavior function?